# pass a ruby variable in f.select onchange function

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The code is as follows.

```
 <% account_id = @account.id %>
    <%= f.select :white_count, options_for_select((1..7), f.object.try(&:white_count)), { label: 'Please select how many fields there are in white', include_blank: '--Select--' }, class: "white-count-#{@water_meter.id}", onchange: 'displayReadingBlocks()' %>
```

I need to pass  account_id as an argument inside the javascript function displayReadingBlocks().

Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Implemented using string interpolation

```
<%= f.select :white_count, options_for_select((1..7), f.object.try(&:white_count)), { label: 'Please select how many fields there are in white', include_blank: '--Select--' }, class: "white-count-#{@water_meter.id}", onchange: "displayReadingBlocks(#{account_id})" %>
```